# How to broadcast streamed data again?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Using AWS-Kinesis to get producers stream data, how would the streamed data get broadcasted to other consumers again? would the consumers do polling? or would there be some kind of events?

For ex: a live tracking app, users stream their long, lat info, so that other users can see their location, in this example, some users streamed their location while others consumed it..

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Producing to `Kinesis` is done separately from consuming it.

A producer can also consume the stream in parallel.

Basically, any record that is produced to the stream - is kept there for at least 24 hours (depending on your configuration).

You can apply as many consumers as you wish, and all of them will consume the same records (unlike a queue `SQS`, where each record is processed exactly once).